# Can not remove sublime text 2 because of installing package control

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

After setting up Sublime Text 2, I tried to install package control but I faced an error. Then every time I open Sublime Text 2, there was an error :

```
Unable to run package setup:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 165, in upgrade
    upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir, datadir, backupdir)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 158, in upgradePackage
    os.path.join(backupdir, base), inhibitOverwrite)
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 90, in upgradeArchive
    writeFile(fname, newar.read(f))
File "./PackageSetup.py", line 18, in writeFile
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fo: 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/halink/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Package Control/package_control/preferences_filename.py'
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix it or how to remove Sublime Text and I can re-install it?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simply revert to freshly installed state.

```
Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-2
```

**To revert to a freshly installed state**, you can:

```
Exit Sublime Text 2
Delete (or move) the data folder, as listed above
Start Sublime Text 2
```

When restarted, a fresh data folder will be created, just as it was the first time you ran Sublime Text 2. Keep in mind that this will also remove all of your settings, and packages you may have installed.

source: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html

If you want to uninstall it here's an example of how to install/uninstall

Open the terminal and use the following commands **to install** Sublime Text 2 Editor:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install sublime-text`

How **to uninstall** Sublime Text 2 Editor:

`sudo apt-get remove sublime-text`

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2`

`sudo apt-get update`

source: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-easily-install-sublime-text-2-editor-in-ubuntu/